# Transform delegate callbacks to SignalProducer events?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa-4

I have an object that is a delegate. There are 6 delegate callbacks informing the delegate about the state of things. I have a `MySpecialEvent` swift enum that represents these states. 
Can you help me figure out how to correctly initialise a `SignalProducer<MySpecialEvent, NoError>` and hook the delegate calls to Producer `next` Events when I instantiate this delegate object?

My expectation is (correct me pls if this is wrong) that the signal producer will be a public `producer` property of the delegate object. Then I can get a reference to this producer, pass it around and basically handle events elsewhere in reactive fashion.

Initially I though that I could have a MutableProperty on the delegate object, I would change it's value inside each delegate call, and this is giving me a producer for free which I then can observe.

UPDATE: I tried this and it actually works.

But conceptually I don't like this because what I am talking about is events, not persistent state values. It's true it's an implementation detail but still. Is that approach right?

Answer (score 1):

What I try to do with Functional Reactive Programming in general is remove the use of Delegates as much as possible.  You are right that it seems a bit more stateful to add a `MutableProperty` to the delegate class.  MutableProperties are kind of a bridge between the stateless and stateful paradigms.

**So, what does this mean?**

Instead of creating a delegate to use for handling events when things change.  Find a way to observe the events as **Signals** and react to events.  An example is probably easiest to understand.

Say you have a modal view that you are presenting, and the **presenting** controller is the delegate of the **presented** view controller.  You pass the presenting controller to the modal...

```
func showModal() {
  let modalVC = ModalViewController()
  modalVC.delegate = self
  self.presentModalViewController(modalVC, animated: true)
}

func modalComplete() {
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  print("All Done with Modal.")
}
```

Then, the presented controller at some point (obviously not showing all the delegate protocol stuff)

```
func allDone() {
  self.delegate?.modalComplete()
}
```

**The FRP way**

Replacing the delegate pattern with **FRP** would result is something like...

```
func showModal() {
  let modalVC = ModalViewController()
  modalVC.completionSignal
    .startWithNext { [weak self] _ in
      self.modalComplete()
    }
  self.presentModalViewController(modalVC, animated: true)
}

func modalComplete() {
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  print("All Done with the FRP Modal.")
}
```

And in your modal you would create a signal you could send something on when it's time to close the modal.

```
let (completionSignal, completionObserver) = SignalProducer<String, NoError>.buffer(1)

func allDone() {
  completionObserver.sendNext("Whatever you want")
  completionObserver.sendComplete()
}
```

Hope this helps.  Working with both delegates and FRP can get confusing, and one of the things I like best about RAC4 is its ability to replace this cumbersome pattern.

You can also use a true `Signal` rather than a `SignalProducer` by defining in the modal view controller like

```
let (completionSignal, completionObserver) = Signal<String, NoError>.pipe()
```

And then just observing it on the parent view controller rather than starting and observing it.